# LUA table with function arguments and passing nil

Tags: lua

Trying to use a table as a lookup for user generated data passed in externally.

```
tab = { ['on']  = function(x) x=x+1 return x end,
        ['off'] = function(x) x=x+2 return x end,
        ['high']= function(x) x=x+3 return x end,
        ['low'] = function(x) x=x+4 return x end
        }
do
   local var=0
   local userData='on'
   
   var = tab[userData](var)
   print(var)
   if var>0 then
      --do something here 
   else
   end

end
```

If the value exists in the table (userData='on') the program works as expected and prints

```
$lua main.lua
1
```

If the value does not exist in the table (userData='fluff') program fails

```
$lua main.lua
lua: main.lua:11: attempt to call a nil value (field '?')
stack traceback:
main.lua:11: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

How can I use a table like this if the keys do not exist?

Comment: Check to be sure that `tab[userData]` returns non-nil before attempting to make a function call with the result.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use metatable for keys not exists.
for example:

```lua
local tab = {}
setmetatable(tab, {__index = function()
    return function(x)
        return x + 1
    end
end})
print(tab['on'](1))
```

the print result is: 2

Answer (score 3):

The best solution is to not have the user enter invalid values in the first place.

If you cannot be sure `userData` is a key in `tab` you should check it befor using it to index `tab`

```
if not tab[userData] then
  print("invalid userdata")
  return
end
```

If you need `tab[userData]` to default to a function you can do something like this

```
tab[userData] = tab[userData] or function () print("I'm your default function!") end
```

or use a metatable as shown in another answer.